# LoadError:PyCall.PyError ("\$(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/pyfncall.jl:44 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call)

Tags: julia, conda

I am getting the following Error for PyCall and am on Julia v 1.2.0

```
ERROR: LoadError: PyCall.PyError("\$(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/pyfncall.jl:44 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr, kw))))", PyCall.PyObject(Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct} @0x00007f9ea56a2520), PyCall.PyObject(Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct} @0x00007f9db65dcca8), PyCall.PyObject(Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct} @0x00007f9d004f9f08))
Stacktrace:
 [1] pyerr_check at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/exception.jl:60 [inlined]
 [2] pyerr_check at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/exception.jl:64 [inlined]
 [3] macro expansion at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/exception.jl:84 [inlined]
 [4] __pycall!(::PyCall.PyObject, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Ptr{Nothing}) at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/pyfncall.jl:44
 [5] _pycall!(::PyCall.PyObject, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Tuple{String,String,String,String,String,Float64,String,Float64}, ::Int64, ::Ptr{Nothing}) at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/pyfncall.jl:29
 [6] _pycall!(::PyCall.PyObject, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Tuple{String,String,String,String,String,Float64,String,Float64}, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/pyfncall.jl:11
 [7] #call#111(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/pyfncall.jl:89
 [8] (::PyCall.PyObject)(::String, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at /home/omkar/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/pyfncall.jl:89
```

I have already tried `update` and below is the setup for the build file

```
ENV["PYTHON"] = " " 
Pkg.build("PyCall")

using PyCall, Conda
pyexec = pyimport("sys").executable
```

Comment: The environment variable `PYTHON` should actually be the empty string (`""`), not a string containing one space (`" "`).  What happens if you repeat the setup with `ENV["PYTHON"] = ""`?